# Replace ")" by ") " if the parenthesis is followed by a letter or a number using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regexp-replace

```py
import re

input_text = "((PL_ADVB)dentro ). ((PL_ADVB)ñu)((PL_ADVB)    9u)"

input_text = re.sub(r"\s*\)", ")", input_text)
print(repr(input_text))
```

How do I make if the closing parenthesis `)` is in front of a letter (uppercase or lowercase) it converts the `)` to `)`, so that the following output can be obtained using this code...

```
"((PL_ADVB) dentro). ((PL_ADVB) ñu)((PL_ADVB) 9u)"
```

Comment: Why are some excess spaces removed? Is that part of what you want the regex to perform?

Comment: according to the output it should also strip extra spaces in matches `)    9` --> `) 9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform consecutive substitutions (including stripping extra spaces through all the string):

```
input_text = "((PL_ADVB)dentro ). ((PL_ADVB)ñu)((PL_ADVB)    9u)"

input_text = re.sub(r"\s*\)", ")", input_text)
input_text = re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", input_text)  # strip extra spaces
input_text = re.sub(r"\)(?=[^_\W])", ") ", input_text)
print(repr(input_text))
```

---

```
'((PL_ADVB) dentro). ((PL_ADVB) ñu)((PL_ADVB) 9u)'
```

Comment: Replace `(?=\w)` by `(?=[^\W_])`

Comment: @Corralien What is the advantage of replacing that \w by \W ?

Comment: @Matt095, `\w` covers letters, numbers and char `_`. So (as you requested only letters and numbers) to workaround that `_` char another pattern is applied

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. See [regex](https://regex101.com/r/92IISR/1)

```
re.sub(r"\)[A-Za-z]", ")", input_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single pattern with a lambda, and do the replacement by checking if the group 1 value exists.

**Explanation**

- `\s*\)` Match optional whitespace chars and `)`
- `(?:\s{2,})?` Optionally match 2 or more whitespace chars
- `([^\W)])?` Optional capture group 2, match a non word character other than `)`

See the [regex101 matches](https://regex101.com/r/0Rkrwr/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QnXm1K).

```
import re

pattern = r"\s*\)(?:\s{2,})?([^\W)])?"
input_text = "((PL_ADVB)dentro ). ((PL_ADVB)ñu)((PL_ADVB)    9u)"
res = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: ") " + m.group(1) if m.group(1) else ")", input_text)
print(res)
```

Output

```
((PL_ADVB) dentro). ((PL_ADVB) ñu)((PL_ADVB) 9u)
```